# Can't add User to Network Drive, Already added through Security Tab on Windows Server

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares

I have a windows server with a bunch of network drives connected to a bunch of computers. I want to give access to a drive, to one of the computers. I added this computer through the network drive's security tab, and searched for that username, yet the computer still does not have the permission to access this computer.

Comment: Ask the user to log out then back in, or better yet, to restart his/her computer. If this doesn't work, you may have to reset permissions for this user on this drive manually. Did you grant permissions to the whole drive, or specific folders on the drive? Are those folders shared by other users, with the same rights, or elevated rights compared to that specific user? EDIT: is the computer in question used by only one person or is it shared among, say, a team?

Comment: @Didier I logged out of this computer multiple times, restarted it, just dont dare to restart the windows server

Comment: Also, its a group of computers used by a team. Each has their own computer and each has access to different drives. I tried adding people to the groups(there were groups for different parts of our team in the permissions) and seeing if that gave the computers access but that didnt work :(

Comment: Is the computer in question on the same subnet as the others who can access this shared folder? Also, what if you tried a per-user approach instead of a per-machine one? If the locked-out user always logs in to the same workstation, and if that workstation's IP doesn't change, it could solve your problem. Not rebooting the server is something I understand perfectly... :-) Been there, done that (as little as possible)... EDIT: alternatively, you could make the recalcitrant PC inherit permissions from one that can access this folder.

Comment: @Didier I know that all the computers are connected to a switch and they share the same network. And that all computers atleast have access to a certain drive on the server. I am now adding user accounts through the security tab. https://i.imgur.com/ML2DTUD.png I am trying to add the user highlighted to be able to access this drive but he still cant.

Comment: If the user (Mark?) you're trying to add is already in the group above, then you don't need to add him individually. Their connecting through a switch could be a factor if the error message says that the folder or drive Mark is trying to open cannot be found. It would mean there's a routing issue. If the message says Mark isn't authorized to open that folder, it's a permission issue. Either remove Mark from the group and grant him individual access, or leave him in the group and check if his user account isn't restricted for some reason, or locked, or has expired. Depends on the exact message.

Comment: @Didier someone on discord was able to help me! So I just needed to add the user on the share tab in permissions on the server manager app

Comment: OK. Strange that you had to do it this way since it's doubling as an interface for Active Directory, but if it worked this way, so much the better!